# Происхождение названий драгоценных камней: гранат, изумруд, смарагд, рубин

Tags: этимология

Первым обработчиком драгоценных камней следует считать воду. Перекатываясь в русле ручья или в полосе прибоя камни постепенно приобретают округлую форму. До XV века форму природных Д. камней не исправляли. Их полировали и заключали в оправу (кабошоны) или просверливали для нанизывания на нить (бусины). https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5b33267990cdf400a9227292/kogda-poiavilas-ogranka-kamnei-5bc1d44cbfa02800a97a4c51

Научной системы классификации минералов в те времена не было, но старинные названия Д. камней наверняка хранят в себе попытки их систематизации по таким признакам, как доминирующий цвет, степень прозрачности, форма, видимые включения (неоднородности в составе), сложность в обработке (твердость), место рождения (обнаружения).
Формой и цветом полированные (не ограненные) камни напоминали собой плоды ягодных растений и по сходству с ягодой (как живая!) и могли получить свои названия.

Насколько вероятным считается «ягодное» происхождение следующих исторических названий Д. камней: гранат (подобный зернышку граната), изумруд (виноград-камень), смарагд (смородина), рубин (рябина)?

Answer (score 3):

Единственное из перечисленных названий драгоценных камней, которое может иметь хоть какое-то отношение к фруктам, это *гранат*.

*Гранат* традиционно прослеживается до латинского *granatus*, производного от *granum* (зерно), что принято считать отсылкой к семенам помеграната. При этом стоит отметить, что слово *granum* описывает любое семя, не обязательно граната. Однако, уже в латыни название граната отражает именно наличие семян внутри фрукта. Само слово восходит дальше к реконструкции прото-индо-европейского. Кстати, русское слово *зерно* приходится ему дальним родствеником.

*Изумруд*, равно как и *смарагд* (разные варианты, произошедшие из общего источника), восходят к персидскому *zomorrod*/*uzmurud*, откуда прослеживается до греческого *smáragdos*. Уже в этот момент, слово обозначает изумруд. Дальше можно найти корни в семитских языках, где значение смещается в сторону "блеск, мерцание".

*Смородина* же восходит к куда менее заманчивому *смород*, описывающему неприятный запах её листьев (да-да, родственное слово *смрад*), и это уже идет до реконструкции в прото-индо-европейском **smord-o-s*, имеющей примерно тоже значение. Оттуда же происходит, например, латинское *merda* (навоз, экскременты, дерьмо—в последнем значении употребляется в качестве восклицаний аналогично русскому бранному смыслу).

*Рубин* восходит к латинскому *rubeus* (красный), откуда прослеживается до прото-индо-европейской реконструкции **h₁rewdʰ-* (красный). Кстати, слово *рыжий* является дальним родственником.

*Рябина* же восходит к прото-славянскому *arębъ* (рябчик, куропатка) т.е. буквально "птичья ягода". Если интересно, то название птицы восходит к тем же истокам, что и *рябой* т.е. пятнистый.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Придется согласиться, что ягодные ассоциации оказались ложными. Только жаль немного, что Эсмеральда будет теперь не сладкой и пъянящей, а как изумруд - холодной и зеленоватой.